# Join results of Duplicate column name 'year'

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

I want something like this (working example):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT year FROM
    (SELECT year FROM classbook WHERE year > 1
        UNION ALL SELECT year + 1 as year FROM classbook WHERE year > 1) qu
ORDER BY year
```

I tried:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT year FROM
    (SELECT year, year + 1 as year FROM classbook WHERE year > 1) qu
ORDER BY year
```

But this throws `Duplicate column name 'year'`.

What's the simplest (a simpler) way to accomplish this?

I'm using MySQL database.

Comment: The simplest is to use union - you say it works? Why are you looking for another solution?

Comment: `SELECT year, year + 1 as year` - this is the problem. You cannot have two columns with the same name/alias.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @boisvert because simpler code is better. It contains fewer bugs, it's easier to maintain... It might even be faster (probably not in SQL, since it reinterprets to optimize).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first query is fine.  You don't need a subquery:

```
SELECT year
FROM classbook
WHERE year > 1
UNION   -- on purpose to remove duplicates
SELECT year + 1 as year
FROM classbook
WHERE year > 1
ORDER BY year
```